# Limit a SQL MAX to rows matching a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, max, where-clause

I have a table of alarms that have various values including a severity and a flag for being obsolete, both as an int.

I'm trying to build a CASE statement that will return the minimum severity (1) if all are obsolete and get the max severity that is not obsolete if there are non-obsolete alarms.

Obsolete will only ever be 0 or 1 so if the sum of that and the count of all alarms are the same they are all obsolete, I'm having issues with the other case (where SOME are obsolete but others are not and ignoring the severity of the obsolete ones).

This seems like something simple such as the following should work:

```
(CASE
   WHEN (SUM(`al`.`OBSOLETE`) = COUNT(`al`.`ALARM_ID`)) THEN MIN(`al`.`SEVERITY`)
   ELSE (MAX(`al`.`SEVERITY`) WHERE `al`.`OBSOLETE` != 1)
END) AS `overallSeverity`,
```

But I get the error:

> Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis'

The following works as valid SQL but will return the max even if it is obsolete:

```
(CASE
   WHEN (SUM(`al`.`OBSOLETE`) = COUNT(`al`.`ALARM_ID`)) THEN MIN(`al`.`SEVERITY`)
   ELSE (MAX(`al`.`SEVERITY`))
 END) AS `overallSeverity`,
```

Basically, how can I get the max of a column excluding rows that match a WHERE?

Comment: You cant declare a WHERE within your fields selection. Try building a subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subqueries like that require at least `SELECT` and `FROM` clauses:

```
(CASE
   WHEN (SUM(`al`.`OBSOLETE`) = COUNT(`al`.`ALARM_ID`)) 
   THEN MIN(`al`.`SEVERITY`)
   ELSE (SELECT MAX(`al`.`SEVERITY`) FROM tablename WHERE `al`.`OBSOLETE` != 1)
END) AS `overallSeverity`,
```

replacing `tablename` with whatever the table's named.

Comment: At first this was still ignoring obsolete but changing != to <> seems to make this work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should  use aggregation function (sum, max, min, avg..) in having condition and not in  where

```
select  .......
from ...
where 
having (CASE
  WHEN (SUM(`al`.`OBSOLETE`) = COUNT(`al`.`ALARM_ID`)) THEN MIN(`al`.`SEVERITY`)
   ELSE (MAX(`al`.`SEVERITY`))
  END)
```

The aggregation result can be evaluated only in having clause